# Dynamic logging based on configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, aop, postsharp

I have a requirement where I have to add a capability to my application,
using which based on a configuration file logs will be added in code.
So for example if my class name is **abc.cs**, user will make following entry in the config file .

```
<entry typeName = "mynamespace.abc">
<LineNumbers ="1,2,3,10, 12">
</entry>
```

Now for the line numbers 1,2,3,10,12 before they are reached in code flow a log entry will be created in log file mentioning "Line number x reached in type y".

We want this to happen at run time without any code changes or dll changes ,
just when more logging is required add type and line number in the config file.

On going through internet I could find that AOP can help in this, but I am really not sure which framework or approach can help in achieving that.

Looking forward for guidelines for same.
My application uses c# and .net framework.

Comment: AOP frameworks in general and PostSharp in particular are designed to inject code (advices) in strictly defined pointcuts such as method entry, method exit etc. Intercepting arbitrary lines of code based on line number is not supported in AOP.

Answer (score 0):

When this kind of logging is required, you could attach a (remote) debugger and configure action breakpoints to log when certain lines are hit.

Answer (score 0):

its possible to get the requered result with PDB reader.
please see: [Common Compiler Infrastructure: Metadata API](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/)
with that tool you can follow code location by type.

> The CCI Metadata API allows applications to efficiently analyze or
>   modify .NET assemblies, modules, and debugging (PDB) files. CCI
>   Metadata supports the functionality of the .NET **System.Reflection and
>   System.Reflection.Emit** APIs, but with much better performance. It also
>   provides additional functionality that is not available in either .NET
>   API.